# C# - Create List of Tasks for a Quadcopter

Tags: c#, list

I have  a multilined textbox where I can write missons for a drone.

Example:

> 10 levantar
>
> 10 goto 50,40
>
> 10 goto 20,20
>
> 10 mayday
>
> 10 aterrar

I want to create a list that does this missoes step by step. Something like: takeoff, after takeoff goto that position and when reaches that positon goto the next, etc..

**My question is:** *Is there a way to group this text on a list and when it finishes that task i simply remove the first position of the list and does the next?*

```
private void executa_missao()
    {
        string[] linhas_separadas = null;
        string[] pontos_separados = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < tb_missoes.Lines.Length; i++)
        {              
            linhas_separadas = tb_missoes.Lines[i].Split(null);


            for(int k=0;k<drone.Length;k++)
            {
                listas_posicoes[k] = new List<PointF>();        
                if (linhas_separadas[0] == drone[k].ip_drone_final)
                {
                    if (linhas_separadas[1] == "goto")
                    {                  
                        pontos_separados = linhas_separadas[2].Split(',');
                        drone[k].posicao_desejada = new PointF(Convert.ToSingle(pontos_separados[0]), Convert.ToSingle(pontos_separados[1]));
                        //guarda na lista as posicoes pretendidas
                        listas_posicoes[k].Add(new PointF(Convert.ToSingle(pontos_separados[0]), Convert.ToSingle(pontos_separados[1])));
                    }
                    else if (linhas_separadas[1] == "levantar")
                    {
                        drone[k]._droneClient.FlatTrim();
                        drone[k]._droneClient.Takeoff();
                        drone[k].subir_ate_altura = true;

                    }
                    else if (linhas_separadas[1] == "aterrar")
                    {
                        drone[k]._droneClient.Land();
                    }
           }
        }
```

**Atm it's trying to do every step at the same time. I want to make step-by-step.**

Comment: My initial thoughts are to use the [Queue class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx). How would the code know when the drone has completed its task?

Comment: For example: after takeoff altitude is like 1 meter. After 1 meter goes to the next step. Position is when actual position == desired position goes to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `List<T>`

Then you can use the `.Dequeue()` function to get your current command, and remove it from the queue.

Creating sample working code for this behaviour can get very complicated and would take me a while, but the basic pattern would look as such:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    public abstract bool IsComplete { get; }
    public abstract void Execute();
}
public static class CommandExecutor
{
    public static Queue<Command> commands;
    public static Command current;

    public static void Update()
    {
        if (commands.Count > 0
            && (current == null || current.IsComplete))
        {
            current = commands.Dequeue();
            current.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Where the `Update()` method is called in recurring intervals.

Comment: That might work. But I queue the string itself or the  actual drone commands?

Comment: What does that <T> means? What's that type?

Comment: It is a type parameter, you have to pass in a type to use it, so if i was you, i would create a `Command` class, and then create a `Queue<Command>` then you can loop through the commands in the queue, and execute each one like `command.Execute()`

Comment: can you exemplify please? I'm kinda new in C#. thanks for ur help.